# ADF Copy Activity to JSON Sink Expanding Decimal Precision

Tags: json, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm pulling Data from a Rest End Point . The value of the the JSON property which i get using Postman and via C# code is

```
"value": 9.9516
```

But after copy activity from Rest API Source and JSON sink( also tried inline sink), the decimal precision expands

[image]

```
"value":9.9515999999999991
```

Update:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to use dataflows instead of copy activity. The C# code might be rounding the data up to 4 decimal places but copy activity is directly storing the data as is.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Cannot use data flows as it requires schema definition.C# code is not rounding off the data, we have confirmed the data in the API vendor database. ADF is the culprit here.

Comment: Please clarify this: The actual value returned by API is `9.9516` but ADF is instead receiving `9.9515999999999991`? Is this the case?

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Correct , In  the JSON file written by ADF I get `9.9515999999999991` while API is actually providing `9.9516`

Comment: How are you defining schema in copy data activity? And can you please call the API using `web activity` and provide an image of debug output response returned from API.

Comment: @SaideepArikontham Please see the attached screenshot, the sink is defined this way and the schema is empty. It is just a JSON sink, as the schema will vary based on each API.

Comment: I think one option is to round the decimals while using this file for any operation. I don't think ADF would randomly add decimal precision to values. Also please try rechecking the response. There might not be a way to dynamically do it while receiving the response